# What is the better way to call multiple services in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, request, alamofire

I have 5 different services requests to load into same UItableView for each cells.

What is the best way to approach in order to do this.

```
https://example.com/?api/service1
https://example.com/?api/service2
https://example.com/?api/service3
https://example.com/?api/service4
https://example.com/?api/service5

let url = "https://example.com/?api/service1
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters:nil encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
    .responseJSON { response in
        print(response.result.value as Any)   // result of response serialization
}
```

repeat the same Alamofire five times with different services name there is another way to implement it.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems did you run into exactly?

Comment: Problem is what is the best approach for implementing it.  I just stuck to iterate loop the services call or there is request array for implementing it.

Comment: What approaches do you have in mind, and which one did you try yourself? There are a lot of possible approaches, you have to narrow your question down.

Comment: What kind of better?  Do the requests depend on each other?  Do you want them on separate threads?

Comment: I want to call 5 services  and resultant need to shows at same time.

Comment: @PhillipMills no request do not depends on each other!

Comment: Is there any request array concept?

Comment: @wvteijlingen I got approach for looping 5 times with different parameters strings appends to services and fetch the response results.

Comment: Look at using a `DispatchGroup` to perform multiple async tasks and wait for them all to complete

Answer (score 3):

Look at using a [DispatchGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup) to perform multiple async requests and wait for them all to complete.

For each task you call `group.enter()` and in its completion handler when you know that request has finished you call `group.leave()`. Then there is a notify method which will wait for all requests to call `leave` to tell you that they have all finished.

I have created an example in a Playground (which will fail with errors because of the URL's used)

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let serviceLinks = [
    "https://example.com/?api/service1",
    "https://example.com/?api/service2",
    "https://example.com/?api/service3",
    "https://example.com/?api/service4",
    "https://example.com/?api/service5"
]

// utility as I've not got alamofire setup
func get(to urlString: String, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        completion(data, response, error)
    }
    task.resume()
}

let group = DispatchGroup()

for link in serviceLinks {
    group.enter() // add an item to the list 
    get(to: link) { data, response, error in
        // handle the response, process data, assign to property
        print(data, response, error)
        group.leave() // tell the group your finished with this one
    }
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    //all requests are done, data should be set
    print("all done")
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

You probably won't be able to just loop through the URL's like I have though because the handling of each service is probably different. You'll need to tweak it based on your needs.

There is alot more information about `DispatchGroups` available online such as [this article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5371-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-2-2)

Comment: I have parameter for token and api_name for the URL with out changing url how to pass parameters to the request ? Its really helps me in elevate few more learning items from you!

Comment: I have an older project on guthub that can give you some good tips on networking, you will need to update it to swift 4 though but that should be easy. https://github.com/martinjkelly/On-The-Map/blob/master/On%20The%20Map/OTMClient.swift. Check the fetch method in this file. you can pass params, headers etc